# Magnetic field at the end of semi infinite solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose a semi infinite solenoid carrying a current $I$ , and have a $n$ number of turns per unit length . How can we calculate the magnetic field at a distance $z$ from the axis of solenoid in the plane of one of the flat faces.
When z = 0 the answer easily comes to be $B = \frac{\mu_oNI}{2}$

How to find if for other values of $z$.

Along with this also can we also state the specific z for which the field is perpendicular to the axis of solenoid.

Comment: When you imagine completing the solenoid with another semi-infinite piece, you will get twice the field everywhere on the joining face. But field inside solenoid is uniform. From this it follows that axial component of field of a single semi-infinite solenoid is the same throughout on its end face. Transverse component is more difficult, this can be calculated using the Biot-Savart formula.

Comment: [Calculation of the off-axes Magnetic Field for Finite-length Solenoids](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjToZurjMOCAxUPVkEAHecwAY0QFnoECA0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npsm-kps.org%2Fjournal%2Fdownload_pdf.php%3Fdoi%3D10.3938%2FNPSM.70.667&usg=AOvVaw1v9cf61bXI8KTUKbbrKIWC&opi=89978449)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by a conform transformation in the z-r plane:
see "Moon/Spencer, A field theory handbook  pdf download"

E5

[image: Table conformal maps]

p 61

[image: maxwell curves]